# How do I create a VBA loop in Access for the code displayed below?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim Q As Integer, F As Integer, V As Integer, hours As Integer, hours1 As Integer, hours2 As Integer, hours3 As Integer, hours4 As Integer, hours5 As Integer, hours6 As Integer, 


Q = Forms!frmweekhrs!txtWeeks * t
F = 0.9 * Q
V = 1.1 * Q
hours = Sheet.Range("b4").Value
hours1 = Sheet.Range("b5").Value
hours2 = Sheet.Range("b6").Value
hours3 = Sheet.Range("b7").Value
hours4 = Sheet.Range("b8").Value
hours5 = Sheet.Range("b9").Value
hours6 = Sheet.Range("b10").Value


If hours1 > F And hours1 < V Then
Sheet.Range("b5").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
Sheet.Range("b5").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

If hours2 > F And hours2 < V Then
Sheet.Range("b6").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
Sheet.Range("b6").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

If hours3 > F And hours3 < V Then
Sheet.Range("b7").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
Sheet.Range("b7").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

If hours4 > F And hours4 < V Then
Sheet.Range("b8").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
Sheet.Range("b8").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If`

If hours5 > F And hours5 < V Then
Sheet.Range("b9").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
Sheet.Range("b9").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

If hours6 > F And hours6 < V Then
Sheet.Range("b10").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
Sheet.Range("b10").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
```

This code scans person hours and labels the amounts either green or red depending on if the number is in good or bad standing. I have about 40 more of these and don't know how to create a loop for this, please let me know if you require any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Q As Integer, F As Integer, V As Integer, hours As Integer

Q = Forms!frmweekhrs!txtWeeks * t
F = 0.9 * Q
V = 1.1 * Q
'initiate loop over focal rows
For i = 4 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    hours = ActiveSheet.Range("b" & i).Value

    If hours > F And hours < V Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("b" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("b" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great!  Wow, got rid of so much redundant unnecessary code.

Comment: You used the fixed value i = 4  To 10. How do I set it  I = 4 to (an undetermined amount) if it's continuously increasing or decreasing in value for the amount of records to highlight?

Comment: I edited my answer to find the last row. To find the first row, I'd have to know more about how the data are structured. Are there headers?

Comment: The previous DBA included a lot of different variables which deleted extra excel spreadsheets, named and identified the current one, so using the updated code produces the error 'subscript out of range'. Should I replace the "Sheet1" with the active sheet's object name? If you need more detail let me know. Also, there is a header and the first row is fixed to begin at 5 so beginning with 'i=5' worked great.

Comment: Yes, you can either use `ActiveSheet.Range([...])` notation or `Sheets("Sheet1")`, with the active sheet's object name like you said depending on the context.